# How to get a hash code as integer in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, hashcode

What I want to do is implement a hash trick in R.

Code below:

```
library(digest)
a<-digest("key_a", algo='xxhash32')
#[1] "4da5b0f8"
```

This returned a hash code in a character type. Is there any way I can turn it into a integer?
Or is there any other package to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That output is a hex (base 16) string. Use following function to change it to decimal. Taken from another forum post but link does not work anymore (2017).

```
hex_to_int = function(h) {
  xx = strsplit(tolower(h), "")[[1L]]
  pos = match(xx, c(0L:9L, letters[1L:6L]))
  sum((pos - 1L) * 16^(rev(seq_along(xx) - 1)))
}
```

Output

```
> hex_to_int(a)
[1] 1302704376
```

But better answer is **strtoi**: as @Andrie said and @Gedrox answered, **[base::strtoi](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strtoi.html)** function works in the same way.

```
strtoi("4da5b0f8", 16)
[1] 1302704376
```

Comment: Very nice, but note that R has a built-in function to do this, called `strtoi`, as suggested by another answer.

Comment: Nice, but how do you avoid integer overflow?

Comment: `stringr::str_sub(a, end=-2)` removes the last character of `a` to ensure it fits within a 32 bit integer.

Comment: But how to strtoi() this hash (sha256 result): "494414ded24da13c451b13b424928821351c78fce49f93d9e1b55f102790c206"?

Comment: This number is bigger than .Machine$integer.max. strtoi will not work on it. hex_to_int will also give you approximate double. You need to write custom code to get exact string representation.

Answer (score 9):

Since version 0.6.19, `digest` has a `digest2int` function, though there is no choice of algorithm. The algorithm used is Jenkin's one_at_a_time.

```
digest::digest2int("key_a")
#> [1] 1414969953
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a built in function `base::strtoi`:

```
> strtoi("4da5b0f8", 16)
[1] 1302704376
```