# R: Fast hashing of strings to integer modulo n?

Tags: r, hash

I have a vector of strings and I would like to hash each element individually to integers modulo n.

In [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442991/how-to-get-a-hash-code-as-integer-in-r) it suggests an approach using `digest` and `strotoi`. But when I try it I get `NA` as the returned value

```
library(digest)
strtoi(digest("cc", algo = "xxhash32"), 16L)
```

So the above approach will not work as it can not even produce an integer let alone modulo of one.

What's the best way to hash a large vector of strings to integers modulo n for some n? Efficient solutions are more than welcome as the vector is large.

Comment: For speed, you could also consider replacing the modulo reduction with multiply and shift.

Comment: @ThomasMueller not obvious how to do for a novice

Comment: A good description is in the blog post [A fast alternative to the modulo reduction](https://lemire.me/blog/2016/06/27/a-fast-alternative-to-the-modulo-reduction/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [Rcpp implementation](https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame/blob/master/src/hashstr2i.cpp) using code from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114085/fast-string-hashing-algorithm-with-low-collision-rates-with-32-bit-integer) and the resultant code is quite fast even for large-ish string vectors.

To use it

```
if(!require(disk.frame)) devtools::install_github("xiaodaigh/disk.frame")
modn = 17
disk.frame::hashstr2i(c("string1","string2"), modn)
```

Answer (score 2):

R uses 32-bit integers for integer vectors, so the range of representable integers is restricted to about +/-2*10^9. `strtoi` returns `NA` because the number is too big.

The `mpfr`-function from the `Rmpfr` package should work for you:

```
mpfr(x = digest("cc`enter code here`", algo = "xxhash32"), base = 16)
[1] 4192999065
```

Comment: seems quite slow when I applied to a large vector.